# Error Installing rails: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.4, >= 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to install rails after having installed ruby 2.4.1p111 on windows 8.1 from 'Start Command Prompt with Ruby(this is just like command prompt that got installed with ruby)'.

I use the command `gem install rails` and after a few seconds of pause the Title of the question is thrown as error.

I tried the command `gem install nokogiri -v 1.7.1` and it throws the same error.

If I run `gem list`, it does not list nokogiri at all.

A possible solution I came across read. *Change nokogiri version in gem `Gemfile` with some command `gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.8'`*. I don't know if that even applies to the version of rails I have installed. If this is the solution, how do I implement it?

How do I rectify this error and install rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently there is an issue<sup>1</sup> in Nokogiri compatibility with Ruby 2.4+, you can check the report [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1618); it will be fixed in Nokogiri 1.8.0.

In the meantime, you could use Ruby 2.3.4, until version 1.8.0 is released.

> I don't know if that even applies to the version of rails I have
>   installed.

No, it don't since you will be downgrading Nokogiri version and will not solve the compatibility issue. That worked for users whose Ruby version was prior to **2.1.0**

<sup>1</sup> *Please notice (as pointed out in the comments) that this a **Windows-only** issue.*

Edit:

You can update now your gemfile:

```
gem "nokogiri", (RUBY_VERSION >= "2.1" ? "~> 1.8" : "~> 1.6.8")
```

Comment: To make it clear, this is a **Windows-only issue**. It's because of things like this that developers always strongly recommend working on a unix machine (or VM) if at all possible.

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for pointing that out, i'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that. I'll use v 2.3.3 for the time being.

Comment: @TomLord Is there going to be security loophole in my application if I use an older version to build it?

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma I'd always recommend using the latest patch release of a given minor version - so in this case, use [`v2.3.4`](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/03/30/ruby-2-3-4-released/), not `2.3.3`. This is, in part, because security fixes will always be released as patches -- so if a new security issue is found, it should be fixed in `2.3.5`. Currently, versions `2.2.x`, `2.3.x` and `2.4.x` are still supported - so you should be fine from a security standpoint using `2.3.4`.